How the koin module hierarchy works
I have a modularized Android project that contains a lot of Koin's modules, each project feature contains its own activity, layout, data layer and dependencies. In the app startup Koin is started, and when each feature is started I launch a loadKoinModule with respective feature modules. My doubts are about Koin's module hierarchy: if I load a Koin module with a factory or singleton that has already been loaded, what's the behavior? If I unload a Koin module that contains a factory or singleton from a previously loaded module, will both be unloaded? Koin has aAn function called allowOverride(boolean = true) which can be accessed in startKoin scope. Do we have a performance loss with this set to true?
Examples:

case 1:
start koin and load main module ->
start feature 1 ->  load feature 1 modules ->
start feature 2 ->
load feature 2 modules that has some factory or singleton equals feature 1 module ->
what's the behavior?


case 2:
start koin and load main module ->
start feature 1 ->
load feature 1 modules ->
start feature 2 ->
load feature 2 modules that has some factory or singleton equals feature 1 module ->
close feature 2 ->
unload feature 2 modules that has some factory equals feature 1 module ->
the factories and singletons in feature 1 modules keeps alive?

I've tried the scenarios previously described and, in case 1, with the allowOverride(boolean = true). The module looks like it loaded again with overriding the Koin definition set before. In case 2, even unloading the lowest level module, the factories and singletons declared before that were the same ones remain alive.
